# python insert function list comprehentions

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am trying to write a 4-5 line code in a single line by using list-comprehentions. But the problem here is that I am not able to use the insert funciton so im wondering if there is a work-around for this?

Original code:

```
def order(text):
    text = text.split()
    for x in text:
        for y in x:
            if y in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'):
                final.insert(int(y)-1, x)

    return final
```

What i have tried so far:

```
return [insert(int(y)-1, x) for x in text.split() for y in x if y in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')]
```

But i have faced the following error:

***NameError: global name 'insert' is not defined***

I have tried to use insert because the task is to re-arrange items in the list by using the number that appears in each word.

for example i have `is2 Th1is T4est 3a` as input and it should come out as: 
 `Th1is is2 3a T4est`

Comment: There is no insert function. `final.insert` is a *method*, and you don't show what `final` actually is (a list, presumably). Also note that you shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects - `list.insert` returns `None`, which I doubt you want a list of.

Comment: 1. What is `final`? 2. List comprehensions _build lists on-the-fly_, so you're now thinking of `insert`ing into literally _nowhere_ as no list has been created yet. 3. Yes, there's no standard function called `insert`, why'd you expect it to exist anyway?

Comment: @ForceBru Final is the list that I have used in the original code. Is there a way to run that expression for this kind of list-comprehention? like " self- insert"

Comment: Also, the `if y in <lots of stuff>` can safely be replaced with `if y in tuple("123456789")` to save space and improve readability. You can save the tuple to a value: `values = tuple("123456789")` and then do `if y in values`, so that the tuple won't be rebuilt each time you arrive at this `if` statement.

Comment: @IdontReallywolf, _where_ do you want to insert stuff? While you're running a list comprehension, no list exists yet, there's nowhere to insert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using list comprehensions, you should just `sort` the list using those numbers in the key function, e.g. extracting the numbers using a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "is2 Th1is T4est 3a"
>>> p = re.compile("\d+")
>>> sorted(s.split(), key=lambda x: int(p.search(x).group()))
['Th1is', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est']
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west! Stupid me, I was still writing an explanation for the exact same code as you. Well done!

Comment: You can also use `int(filter(str.isdigit, x))` instead of the regex. You'll have to use `''.join()` if you want to support Python 3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your original idea by splitting your code up into a few simple functions and make a list of the proper size (filled with `None`s) to hold the final ordering of the words:

```
def extract_number(text):
    return int(''.join(c for c in text if c.isdigit()))

def order(text):
    words = text.split()
    result = [None] * len(words)

    for word in words:
        result[extract_number(word) - 1] = word

    return ' '.join(result)
```

You can also do this in one line using `sorted()`:

```
def extract_number(text):
    return int(''.join(c for c in text if c.isdigit()))

def order(text):
    return ' '.join(sorted(text.split(), key=extract_number))
```